# How to set delay time for answering in php telegram-bot

Tags: php, telegram-bot

There is a PHP Telegram bot which when user send a word, it search in database and find appropriate answer and reply the user's message . 
I dont want this bot send the answers immediately and want to reply by some delay time ,which is saved in database

I used `sleep($row[delay])` before sending back the answer to the user , but when i send some words the bot only reply the first one manytimes continuously.

these are my codes :

```
function delay(){
global $db;
$query="SELECT * FROM Turningoff  WHERE 1";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
sleep($row[delay]);

}


function find($sharh,$chat_id,$message_id)
{
 global $db;

 $query = "select distinct sel.id_forooshande,sel.message from Forooshande As sel 
                 INNER JOIN Kala_forooshande AS ss ON sel.id_forooshande = ss.id_forooshande
                 INNER JOIN Kala AS s ON ss.id_kala=s.id_kala
                                 WHERE  REPLACE(`sharhe_kala`, '/', '')='" . $sharh . "'


 $res = mysqli_query($db, $query);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) //For each forooshande
            {

 $query2 = "SELECT s.mark, s.sharhe_kala FROM Kala AS s
          INNER JOIN Kala_forooshande AS ss ON ss.id_kala=s.id_kala
          INNER JOIN Forooshande AS sel ON sel.id_forooshande = ss.id_forooshande
          WHERE  (REPLACE(`sharhe_kala`, '/', '')='" . $sharh . "')
                                 AND sel.id_forooshande=" . $row[id_forooshande]; //find available kala
 $res2 = mysqli_query($db, $query2);

 $javab = $row[message] . "\r\n";
 while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res2)) {
 $javab .= $row2[mark] . "_" . $row2[sharhe_kala] . "\r\n";



delay();
message($chat_id, urlencode($javab), $message_id);

            }


        }
```

and i call function find() when user send somthing.

should i use database to save each word and answer one by one after delay time ? or it has any other solution ?

Comment: Show the code you tried.

Comment: Code is required to help you. Please post some code as well.